# Is it possible schedule events(GPS On/Off, Wifi On?Off) in workmanager?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-jobscheduler, android-workmanager

From android Oreo we can't use some of the Implicit broad cast receivers(network state,etc..,). Instead of that we can go with job scheduler or Dispatcher. But in I/O 2018 google have introduced a new library Called workmanager.

But here the question arise, how can i handle the system events(On call receive, network state change, GPS On/Off,etc.,) in Work manger? or How can i schedule my work at particular time(without using time calculation)?

If any one have idea on this please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can archive by simply using setInterval method in LocationService class.

Follow the guide to create a Listener using FusedLocaation which gives you a better result on location logic.
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient

```
LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setInterval(5000); 
            // in milliseconds in you case change into 3600000
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
```

Then start a fusedLocation with callback

```
       mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(locationActivity);                
       mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability locationAvailability) {
                super.onLocationAvailability(locationAvailability);
            }
        },null);
```

Thank you